# Running flutter doctor fails

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I run `flutter doctor`, I get the following output:

```
➜  flutter doctor
```

> Because flutter_tools depends on node_preamble 1.4.12 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
> Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools...
> pub get failed (1; Because flutter_tools depends on node_preamble 1.4.12 which
> doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)

Does anyone have any idea how to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a null-safety related conflict, do you have flutter upgraded?